# get non-fixed width div to perfect fit parent without overflowing?

Tags: html, css

Considering the following code:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='right-panel'>Here is the article</div>
    <div class='left-panel'>
        <div class='left-panel-contents'>
            <div class='headline'>
                <h1>HEADLINE</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    min-width: 960px;
    max-width: 1060px;
    background: gray;
}
.right-panel {
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
    width: 760px;
    background: blue;
}
.left-panel {
    background: green;
    height: 200px;
}
.left-panel-contents {
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    // how do I make this fill the width of the left panel
}
.headline {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    line-height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

h1 {
 float: right;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/duw4G/

I'm trying to get the headline text to expand all the way to the right panel. If the left panel contents perfectly filled its parent, this would be possible. If I set it to 100%, overflow: hidden it doesn't solve the problem (the left-panel-contents fill the whole wrapper div width)

Is there any way to adjust my technique to get this to work?

Comment: you have `width: 15%;` in the exact element you want to be 100% width of it's parent? that doesn't make much sense?! Why not just remove it?

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    min-width: 960px;
    max-width: 1060px;
    background: gray;
}
.right-panel {
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
        width:75%;
   padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background: blue;
}
.left-panel {
    background: green;
    height: 200px;
    width:25%;
   padding:0px;
    margin:0px;

}
.left-panel-contents {
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    // how do I make this fill the width of the left panel
}
.headline {
    background: black;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
float:left; position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Yeah.. works nicely if the right panel isn't fixed width. I need the width to be fixed at 760px

Comment: you will have to fix the left panels px as well then. as long as the parent has a fixed width, the child can use 100% width.
it needs a reference point.

Answer (score 0):

`.headline` will be positioned according to the nearest parent with non-static position (i.e. relative or absolute), or to the viewport if no such parent is found.

If it's not required for other purposes, remove `position:relative` from `.left-panel-contents` but add it to `.wrapper`.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/duw4G/9/

Comment: Yeah.. I realize I can do that. I'm trying to get the headline to fill the left panel and only the left panel. That way, when I float the headline text right it lines up next to the right content panel.